# How to create text file automatically using custom maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

How to set value of key for creating file given path in fileset in archetype-metadata.xml .

`<requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="??" />
<requiredProperties/>`

```
        <fileSet filtered="true">
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>

        <!--Filters example -->
        <includes>
            <include>*.txt</include>
            <include>*.properties</include> 
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself.No,we can't do it in automatically without text file placed in respectively path.Please find screen shot for your reference.

**Place text file in archetype-resources and get text file name from user input example:ex.txt**
[image: text file place]

Generated archetype template here you see ex.txt is created in given specific path.

Thanks.

[image]